# "You are going to want to" vs "You will want to"

Tags: future

So I was going to say something the other day like

"After eating this, you are going to want to go there."

I wanted to express that after eating that, the person would end up with a wish about going to some place. It's taken out of context, it could be a restaurant or so here.

1. Is this a correct/good way of saying this? What gave me some doubts is that it was kind of a messy sentence to say. It has two "go" in it and everything.
2. Is perhaps the formulation "After eating this, you will want to go to there" better? As I understood from the thread below though, "you will want to" is more intended for instructions. So how would this fit here?
   [What does "you will want to" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77408/what-does-you-will-want-to-mean)

   3. Is this thing expressed differently in different regions?

The other day was one of the first day of my life that I spent in an English speaking country, so I realized that I've got to step up my game a few notches :)

Comment: That was a great thread, thank you.  I couldn't find the answers to my specific questions in it though.

Comment: OK, you’ve got a point that the juxtaposition of “going to …” and “go” is a little bit awkward. But people say things like “I’m going to go to the meeting” all the time, and nobody bats an eye. I believe that’s not a real problem. But the “you will” formulation is fine, too. As the [What does “you will want to” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/77408/26083) thread’s accepted answer says, it doesn’t necessarily refer to instruction. I would add “If you are assigned to building X, you will want to take a sweater (because it’s always very cold there).” to rsegal’s perfectly good examples.